# Total time difference between login time and logout time-MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

INPUT

```
 userid           login time                               logout time
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1          2012-08-01 16:08:26                     2012-08-01 16:08:29
   2          2012-08-01 16:22:49                     2012-08-01 16:25:44
   3          2012-08-01 16:08:26                     2012-08-01 16:08:29
   3          2012-08-01 16:22:49                     2012-08-01 16:25:44
   3          2012-08-01 16:08:26                     2012-08-01 16:08:29
   4          2012-08-01 16:22:49                     2012-08-01 16:25:44
```

OUTPUT:

```
 userid        date         total time difference b/w login time and logout time
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1        2012-08-01                         00:08:29
   2        2012-08-01                         1:25:44
   3        2012-08-01                         00;55;5
   4        2012-08-01                         1:25:44
```

The query I have tried is:

```
SELECT distinct t.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(t.login_time,\'%d %b %Y\') AS datez,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t.logout_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(t.login_time))) AS timediffe
from login_log t 
where user_id=5 
  AND login_time between '2012-08-01' AND '2012-08-2' 
GROUP BY t.user_id,datez
```

Comment: The question is how much time every user has been logged in? Right @dude?

Comment: The question is 1. how much time every user has been logged in on a particular date? OR 2. How much time every user has been logged in date vise? OR 3. How much total time every user has been logged in?
Now i think best answer will be to answer all these three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to use [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function as:

```
SELECT t.user_id,
       DATE_FORMAT(t.login_time,'%d %b %Y') AS datez,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.logout_time, t.login_time)))) AS timediffe
FROM tic_login_log t
WHERE user_id = 5
      AND login_time between '2012-08-01' AND '2012-08-2'
GROUP BY t.user_id,datez;
```

Comment: but the val will be coming in integer format and not time format

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME` converts it to `TIME` format again. just try this query, should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to required output in question for '2012-08-01'

```
select userid, date(login_time) as Date, sum(timediff(logout_time-login_time) as
'Logged in Time' where date(login_time)='2012-08-01' group by userid;
```

Date vise total logged in time for each user

```
select userid, date(login_time) as Date, sum(timediff(logout_time-login_time) as
'Logged in Time'    group by userid,date(login_time);
```

Total logged in time in history for each user

```
select userid, date(login_time) as Date, sum(timediff(logout_time-login_time) as
'Logged in Time' group by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method find time deifference:

```
select TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '2012-06-20 06:24:43')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIMEDIFF()` method.

Try This :

```
SELECT timediff(your_logout_time,your_login_time);
```

Example :-

```
SELECT timediff('2012-08-02 16:08:29','2012-08-01 16:08:26');
```

Output :- `'24:00:03'`